# Are foreign key nullable by default in ASP.Net MVC 5 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, foreign-keys

I am in a learning phase. And I want to know are foreign keys created by ASP.NET MVC-5 framework in Code First convention using entity framework **nullable by default**? I tried to create foreign key relationship and the foreign key column turns out to be nullable. I had a notion that if I mark a column as foreign key it should be marked as NOT NULLABLE by entity framework.

Below is the example:

One to Many: One "Standard" can have many "Children".

```
public class Children
     {
         public int Id { get; set; }
         public string Name { get; set; }

         public int StandardId { get; set; }
         [ForeignKey("StandardId")]
         public virtual Standard Standard { get; set; }
    }

    public class Standard
     {

         public Standard()
         {
             Children = new List<Children>();
         }
         public int Id { get; set; }
         public string StandardName { get; set; }

         public virtual ICollection<Children> Children { get; set; }
     }
```

With just above configuration, the Foreign Key "StandardId" is coming out to be `Nullable` in database. I just want to know is this expected behaviour? Are foreign keys are suppose to be NULLABLE by DEFAULT or I have not wired up foreign key property properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must tell EF explicitly, that you want this field to be not nullable:

```
public class YourContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Children> Childrens { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Standard> Standards { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder dBModelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Children>().HasRequired(x => x.Standard);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, so what is the best way to acheive non-nullable FK. Shall I decorate "Required" attribute on the FK property or I should follow the approach you answered. Which is the right one and which one I shall always follow?

Comment: This is a matter whether you stick with fluent configuration or attribute configuration. I personally prefer fluent "way"